# How do I get "/login" and "/logout" to map to the Security controller in SilverStripe 3?

Tags: php, security, authentication, routes, silverstripe

I want to use "http://www.mysite.com/login" as the login path for accessing the login form. I then want to do the same with logout ("/logout").

I have tried in /mysite/code/_config/routes.yml to add the following individually:

1. 'login' : 'Security'
2. 'login//$Action/$ID/$Name' : 'Security'

Neither works and I don't like the "/Security/login" path that loads by default. Any way around this to use the system's login tools?

I have also tried creating a user controller that extends the Security class and has a route of "/user/login". It works just fine. But then I struggle to use the User controller for other user page functions like registration and profile because it doesn't extend the Page_Controller class. So it is very annoying.

I would like to unify everything into one class if possible. But I don't think that will be, so the next best thing is to have a "/login" path and a "/logout" path that just point to the dang Security controller and to everything else in the User class.

Thoughts, ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could put some url rewrites in your `.htaccess` file to route those URLs to the Security path:

```
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ Security/logout [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ Security/login [NC,L]
```

Comment: Yeah, I am hoping to do this the "SilverStripe Way" if I can. But this approach is one I have considered. So far I am not too impressed with SilverStripe beyond it's use of object orientation in a PHP-based CMS (haven't really seen it used much in others).